# Why is the student counter skipping a number

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, count, counter

I am trying to build a program which counts each student from 1 - 10. But the output seems to skip 5 after 4 and go straight to 6. 
The output I get is:

```
MathStudent[1]-Smith:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[2]-Jack:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[3]-Victor:  - Count:1
 MathStudent[4]-Mike:  - Count:1
 Science Student[6]-Dave:  - Count:1
 Science Student[7]-Oscar:  - Count:1
 Science Student[8]-Peter:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[9] Philip:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[10] Shaun:  - Count:1
 Computer Student[11] Scott:  - Count:1
```

Main class:

```
public class JavaLab5 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentThread studentThread = new StudentThread();
        studentThread.start();


    }

}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    static int  studentCounter = 1;
    String name;
    private int count = 0;
    public static int instances = 0;

    // Getters
    public  String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String name) {
        if (JavaLab5.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates name,age and gender 
     * with defaults
     */
    public Student() {
        instances++;
        this.name = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param name String with the name
    */
    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Destructor
     * @throws Throwable 
     */
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        //do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
    } 

    /**
     *
     */
    public void getCounter() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return this.name; 
    }

    public String getSubjects() {
      return this.getSubjects();
    }


}
```

ComputerStudent class:

```
public class ComputerStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;


    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @fortanGrade
     * @adaGrade
     */
    public ComputerStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ComputerStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;

    }


    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Computer Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "] " + name + ": "); 
    }
}
```

MathStudent class:

```
public class MathStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;

    /**
     * Default constructor
     * @param name
     */
    public MathStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
        studentCounter++;
    }

    public MathStudent() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
    @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" MathStudent" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    }
}
```

ScienceStudent class:

```
public class ScienceStudent extends Student {
    int studCountObj;
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScienceStudent() {
        super();
    }

    public ScienceStudent(String name) {
        super(name);
        studentCounter++;
        studCountObj=studentCounter;
    }

    /**
     * Display information about the subject
     * @return 
     */
     @Override
    public String getSubjects(){
        return(" Science Student" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
    } 
}
```

StudentThread class:

```
public class StudentThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){
       Student s[] = new Student[10];


        s[0] = new MathStudent("Smith");
        s[1] = new MathStudent("Jack");
        s[2] = new MathStudent("Victor");
        s[3] = new MathStudent("Mike");
        s[4] = new ScienceStudent("Dave");
        s[5] = new ScienceStudent("Oscar");
        s[6] = new ScienceStudent("Peter");
        s[7] = new ComputerStudent("Philip");
        s[8] = new ComputerStudent("Shaun");
        s[9] = new ComputerStudent("Scott");


        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
           for (Student item : s) {
               System.out.print(item.getSubjects() + " - " + "Count:");
               item.getCounter();
           }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
        }

    }

}
```

My question is why is the output skipping 5?

Comment: You have no synchronization of reads and updates to static variables. Either use explicit synchronization, or use `AtomicInteger`s instead.

Comment: And beyond that, your usage of static variables and how you initiatilaze different fields with your different constructors... A lot of potential for improvement there. And for the record: using such static object counters is not a great practice ; and especially the "decrease" part within finalize() has no guarantees to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Science Class:

```
super(name);
studentCounter++;
studCountObj=studentCounter;
```

You first increase the `studentCounter` from 5 to 6 and then assign it to `studCountObj`. Swap that would print 5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this:
MathStudent class:

```
public class MathStudent extends Student {
int studCountObj;

/**
 * Default constructor
 * @param name
 */
public MathStudent(String name) {
    super(name);
    studentCounter++;      //First this
    studCountObj=studentCounter;  //Then this

}

public MathStudent() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Display information about the subject
 * @return 
 */
@Override
public String getSubjects(){
    return(" MathStudent" + "[" + studCountObj + "]" + "-" + name + ": ");
}
```

}

And this:
Student class:

```
public class Student {
static int  studentCounter = 0;      //Start with zero
String name;
private int count = 0;
public static int instances = 0;

// Getters
public  String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

// Setters
public void setName(String name) {
    if (JavaLab5.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Default constructor. Populates name,age and gender 
 * with defaults
 */
public Student() {
    instances++;
    this.name = "Not Set";
}

/** 
 * Constructor with parameters 
 * @param name String with the name
*/
public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Destructor
 * @throws Throwable 
 */
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    //do finalization here
    instances--;
    super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
} 

/**
 *
 */
public void getCounter() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
}
}
@Override
public String toString () {
    return this.name; 
}

public String getSubjects() {
  return this.getSubjects();
}
```

}

In the ScienceStudent class and in the Computer student class you already do this, so when you change this pattern in the Mathstudent class you will get your first output, because when the thread goes to ScienceStudent it will add the number 1 again, you skip a number then.